# Cut opacity of multiple shapes overlapping

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create an overlay of 4 shapes. All of which are triangles which overlap. What I currently have is the opacity of the largest image set to 60% and then each smaller image the opacity reduces by 10%. 
The problem I have is that the smallest shape is therefore the darkest but what I want is for each shape to ignore the opacity of the other shapes.

I have tried selecting the layer and then removing the selection from the bottom layer but this is not 100% accurate as it leave a small gap between layers.

Hope this makes sense, If anyone has any pointers that would be great.

Edit: here is the example i am working with currently... I have managed to use masks to remove the unwanted areas but as you can see there are still small lines overlapping each layer causing it to look bad. is there anyway to get around this?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you can't merely use shades of varying grey as opposed to opacity?

Answer (score 4):

Using masks?

On the image:

- *YELOW TRIANGLE*, *PINK TRIANGLE* and *GREEN TRIANGLE* layers are triangle shapes with a 56% opacity.
- The *YELOW TRIANGLE* selection mask the *PINK TRIANGLE* layer.
- The *YELOW TRIANGLE* and *PINK TRIANGLE* selections mask the *GREEN TRIANGLE* layer.

[image: masks]

With mask there are no gaps:

[image]

If you manage well how to make a mask, there's no possibility at all of getting a white gap

[image: nogap]

Zoom:

[image: zoom]

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but i am still struggling... I have added the image the my original question. I have added masks to the 3 bottom shapes but there is something I am missing as nothing is happening... :|

Comment: Invert the mask layer. If you look the image of the answer, the triangles at the mask are black. At your image the mask has black background and white shape. Just clic the mask to activate it > Menu Image > Adjustments > Invert

Comment: Thanks managed to do that now... see updated image in question.